# Vuelidate Issues with 'this' reference in a requireif

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuelidate

I have a vuejs component that uses vuelidate. Here are my validations:

```
 validations: {
     invoice: {
         dueDate: {
             required,
         },
         tax: {
             required: requiredIf(function () {
                 return this.invoice.taxable;
             }),
        }
    },
```

I have a property called 'invoice' that has a property taxable (boolean) so I need to require the tax field if this property es set to true, but for some reason 'this' is 'undefined' at this moment. I've also tried with the arrow function, same result. I've used this in a vuejs instance in a js file but for some reason when I moved to a separate component it's not working. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: just turn that function to an arrow function cause of functions has it's own context, its not gonna be the same with vue's.

Comment: i've tried that too, same result. thanks for your response!

Comment: Oh aight so there is that requiredIf() function might be also chaging your context?

Comment: actually I don't know. That's a built in validator from vuelidate. I've use before like this but in just vue instance, not in App.vue main component.

Comment: I see, just maybe try to use it `.bind(this)` ?

Comment: Can you compare the component in the documentation with your (full) example? https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-builtin-validators (at the end of this chapter). The documentation clearly states, that `this` should be defined at that point.

Comment: @HalilÇakar .bind(this) didn't work either.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 that was the issue, nested model. It turned out I just used in a non nested model before. Thanks!

Comment: Aight then i'm sorry i couldn't help, but @ssc-hrep3's link might be usefull :) Hope you can find it quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was suggested on by ssc-hrep it turns out that invoice is a nested model that should be passed as argument to the function:

```
validations: {
        invoice: {
            dueDate: {
                required,
            },
            tax: {
                required: requiredIf((invoice) => {
                    return invoice.taxable;
                }),
            }
        },
```